# Maxwell hash(sql_column) write to kafka partition

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using [Maxwell](https://github.com/zendesk/maxwell)  to write changes from a MySql database to Kafka 0.9.0, is there a way to configure Maxwell, so it can partition the data in different topics by a hash function over a column?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `database | table | primary_key | column` for `producer_partition_by` configuration parameter.

As seen in the documentation [here](http://maxwells-daemon.io/producers/),

> HASH_FUNCTION(HASH_STRING) % TOPIC.NUMBER_OF_PARTITIONS
>
> The HASH_FUNCTION is either java's hashCode or murmurhash3. The
> default HASH_FUNCTION is hashCode. Murmurhash3 may be set with the
> kafka_partition_hash option. The seed value for the murmurhash
> function is hardcoded to 25342 in the MaxwellKafkaPartitioner class.
>
> The HASH_STRING may be (database, table, primary_key, column). The
> default HASH_STRING is the database. The partitioning field can be
> configured using the producer_partition_by option.